# Having issues with individual <li> backgrounds and CSS3 transitions

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

EDIT:
I have changed the question as it was too localized and gained negative notes. Hopefully this can apply to others now, although I am struggling to improve it further than this, (sorry for the original).

Q:

How can you use CSS3 to make a margin change appear smooth? This way when you hover over a link which touches the side of the screen it appears to slide out or drop down?

Thanks,

Rick

(The website used in the original question relates to http://www.rickdonohoe.co.uk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked that first problem you already fixed, you can try this one for second solution

`#social_links li{-moz-transition:all 300ms ease-in;
      -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
       -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
       transition: all 300ms ease-in;} #social_links li:hover{background:#74dcff;}`

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to give the `li` a width.

   ```
   #social_links li {
       ...
       width: 20px;
   }
   ```
2. I suggest that you use the jQuery animate function for that.